# Obj model file and animation

Tags: model, wavefront

I am trying to an obj model loader with opengl, i loaded obj models, but i dont have enough information about animaton on obj models. I think, to animation, there are more files with obj model file. So can you explain content of the files? How to can i load the files?

Answer (score 1):

Obj file format does not support animation.

Comment: it is possible with some way. And i asked the way. And the content of the others file which coming when we animated the obj file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can barely understand your broken English. Do you mean there are other files besides the obj file generated? What are those files, and what animation tool are you using?

Comment: Ok i will search fbx to load animated models. Because exporting animated models as obj, can be a problem. But you can look here : http://www.youtube.com/user/thecplusplusguy#p/u/1/_2bPK3lgF-s

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maya to create your model, download the obj animation exporter mel script from here: http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/downloads/scripts-plugins/c/obj-animation-exporter--2

After creating your animation in Maya, if you use this plugin, it will sequence through every frame creating OBJ files so you can use it from animation.

If you are trying to use them in C++, I recommend following thecplusplusguy's tutorials on youtube on how to load the sequence into your program. If you are using Java, I havent found any tutorials yet.